# How do I disable auto-sync in HTC Sync 3.3?

Tags: htc-desire, htc-sync-3.0

Where in HTC Sync is the option to disable synchronization upon connecting the phone to the computer?

There used to be plenty of options in the old versions of HTC Sync. By old versions I mean versions like 2.0 that came with my phone. This is the version I have been using for two years now. I just thought I would update to get all the latest bells and whistles. But little did I know that the newest HTC Sync version is just one big splash screen with a picture of my phone on it and one big SYNC button. And it is very resource hungry.

I am downloading the new HTC Sync Manager right now. But I don't think it's compatible with HTC Desire or other older HTC devices. I think it's mainly made for the HTC One series of phones. So I don't expect much from it, but I'll give it a try anyway. Are there more sync options in Sync Manager than in the regular Sync?

What's a good alternative to HTC Sync that I can use with HTC Desire? Which ones are popular? I don't want anything too fancy. I don't need anything that's too much resource hungry and media focused. Just plain sync tool (PIM).

**Update:** HTC Sync Manager doesn't even start

The first time HTC Sync Manager started it was scanning my computer for media files. I aborted the operation and went to settings to change the language. It prompted me to restart the program so I clicked OK. It restarted and got stock at the splash screen. Now it does that every time and the only way to close it is to terminate the associated process.

[image: htc sync manager]

Great software indeed... it should not stop working just because the user changes the language in the settings. Looks like I will have to install it all over again to erase any conflicting config files and such.

Comment: Do you still have a copy of the install for your old HTC Sync 2.x, is there any reason you can't go back to that if it does everything you're looking for? Newer isn't always better in software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [download page](http://www.htc.com/www/software/htc-sync-manager/) of HTC Sync Manager, HTC Desire phones should be supported.

In my case when I first started the application it started loading all my media files from my pc (which took some time). After everything was loaded, the music etc was stored in my Media gallery of the HTC Sync Manager.

If you want to disable the synchronisation of your phone on connect, disable the option "Automatically start sync when device is connected" under the More tab. In my case that tab was only available when you connect your phone (probably to be able to use different settings for multiple phones).

So maybe you should just try to reinstall the latest HTC Sync Manager, because it should work for your phone too. Just be a little patient.

[image: HTC Sync Manager screenshot]

Comment: Yes, you were right. The phone needs to be connected first before the option actually appears. But I can't verify it right now because I am currently using HTC Sync 3.3.53 because that's where the [link](http://www.htc.com/se/support/news.aspx?p_id=312&p_name=htc-desire) on HTC support website takes me. It wants me to download that instead of HTC Sync Manager. You have to select a product first, before you can see the recommended software for it. So I'm not sure how I got the HTC Sync Manager in the first place.

Comment: It looks like they are maintaining both software. So HTC Sync Manager isn't a natural replacement of HTC Sync. They are probably keeping HTC Sync alive because of compatibility with older phones. I believe this software is used for Windows phones as well as Android, maybe even for their legacy PDAs.

Comment: By the way, the link you posted is broken. "Sorry, the page you’re looking for can’t be found." But I have found [this](https://support.htc.com/alerts_downloads/en/HTC_Sync_and_Sync_Manager_for_all_HTC_Android_Phones) support page. "For HTC One Series, HTC Desire C and HTC Desire X phones, we recommend you use HTC Sync Manager. For older HTC devices, please use HTC Sync instructions below." The product page of HTC Sync Manager is [here](http://www.htc.com/www/software/htc-sync-manager/).

Comment: Entering only http://www.htc.com/www/software/ results in a "page not found". Apparently they don't like the idea of listing all their software on one page to make them easy to find and download. Instead you have to know what sequence of links to click to get to http://www.htc.com/www/software/htc-sync-manager/. So stupid! And for the regular HTC Sync they have a direct link to the EXE file (http://dl4.htc.com/managed-assets/support/software/htc-sync/htc_sync_setup_3.3.21.exe). And they don't allow directory listing of the dl4 download server to allow you to download whatever you want.

Comment: Why do they have to hide their sync software so deeply within the HTML code and force people to do some digging before they find what they're looking for? It seems intentional. I don't like HTC anymore. Not just because of this. I have been with HTC since I bought one of their PDA/GPS navigators. But I feel like their smartphones are always lacking something in terms of quality. It's all good on the outside and on paper, but they never seem to deliver what they promise. Always some hardware defects. And software isn't much better.

Comment: I think HTC is aiming too high. They are not Apple. The sooner they realize that the better. Either that I am just too picky and have high expectations from them. Well, either way... I know I will be jumping over to the Samsung ship this summer. And for syncing I will be looking for an independent alternative tool.

Comment: Updated the link in my post. @Sammy I wouldn't want to trade for an iPhone, especially now that I've seen how bad the UI of iOS 7 is, they're going backwards instead of forwards imo. But that's a totally different discussion :-)

Answer (score 0):

The disable the option "Automatically start sync when device is connected" under the More tab did not work for me. Even after this is unchecked, it still starts the program when I connect my phone. Sometimes I'm just looking for the charge. Yet I have to wait for the program to load on each plug-in, then manually disable. Real pain.